# Electrical gyroscope

Tags: electromagnetism, angular-momentum, gyroscopes

We all love the Gyroscope; basically it has a large angular momentum which stops it from being pushed over.

I'm going to assume ideal conditions for a moment- no resistance etc.

We can create angular momentum from electricity; just electrons moving around.
Thus it should be possible to have a Gyroscope that instead of spinning physically in a way the eye can see, just has a large current through it. It would still have the magical property of not being pushed over.

This would make a neat magic trick and so I'm hoping someone did this experiment but I couldn't find it on youtube.

Is the reasoning correct? Is there a video demonstrating this?

Thanks!

Comment: Related:  [Can a superconducting wire conduct unlimited current?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1060/can-a-superconducting-wire-conduct-unlimited-current)

Comment: There are plenty of ways to hide physically spinning (orbiting) mass from view.  However, if you calculate the total angular momentum for a given DC current I think you'll find you need a nearly weightless structure and wiring , or run the experiment on an asteroid with gravitational force a fraction of a gee

Comment: I mean, even photons have momentum and laser gyroscopes exist, so theoretically yeah but one of the least practical things you could think of. Laser gyroscopes certainly aren't used to exert forces on anything though. Only to measure. Way too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular momentum of electrons circulating in a wire is negligibly small compared to the angular momentum of iron atoms in a wheel rotating around its axle, which makes the iron wheel a practical way of making a gyroscope.

BTW note that the most modern gyroscopes use beams of light circulating around in fiber optic waveguides, and phenomenally sensitive detectors that can measure tiny shifts in the phase of those light beams which occur when the waveguide assembly is rotated about its axis.

Comment: *most modern gyroscopes of any importance that are used for measurement, not actuation as the OP question is asking about. The only gyroscope most people would ever encounter is a toy mechanical one or a MEMs motion control gyroscope in their phone, nouse, or remote.

Comment: Cool didn't know people use light ones for measuring! Incredible.