How big can a current resonance possibly get and what are the sources of power loss?
A damped spring coupled to a sinusoidal force follows the differential equation
$$\ddot{x}+2\beta\dot{x}+\omega_0^2 x = f\cos\omega t .$$
It's well known that the amplitude of the spring in the stationary regime depends on the frequency of the force, $\omega$. In the case where $\beta=0$, the resonance would diverge. Of course, you cannot build a perfectly lossless forced spring, so this limit is purely ideal. Now, the differential equation for a forced RLC circuit is identical
$$\ddot{I} +\frac{R}{L}\dot{I}+\frac{1}{LC}I=  I_0 \cos\omega t, $$
and in this case there are circuits where $R=0$, equivalent to $\beta=0$. Now, as far as I know there is no way to get an "infinite" current within a superconductor. That being the case, what are the sources of losses in this system, that prevent this divergent behavior?

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1060/can-a-superconducting-wire-conduct-unlimited-current

Either the coil is not ideal or you will have radiation of the EM field.

In a system like this, you are correct in asserting that a real-life solution cannot be infinite, so what happens instead is this (details in different systems may vary, and your mileage will be lower in California):
Some component of the system that does not show up explicitly in the ideal model of it you have derived will step in and furnish an "infinity preventer". For example, a straight piece of wire possesses a tiny amount of inductance which is neglected in normal circuit analysis but when the rate of change of current through it becomes enormous then that inductance becomes manifest and prevents the rate of change of current from becoming infinite.
Similarly, that same piece of wire is capacitively coupled to ground, where that capacitance is extremely tiny (but not zero). So, for DC analysis we ignore it completely but at UHF frequencies (where there might be a lurking resonance ready for excitation) that capacitance will present a dead short and prevent the resonance from diverging.

Also, thinking about it more, since the stationary solution is an alternating current this is basically going to behave like an antenna that emits radiation (depending on the geometry of the circuit).
